# Corona SDK Lua, How do I make a finger drawing/painting app?

Tags: ios, sdk, lua, drawing, coronasdk

I am fairly new to Lua and I have written the following code.

```
   display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

--Create the 'brush'
function paint(event)
    locationX = event.x
    locationY = event.y
    brush = display.newCircle(locationX, locationY, 5)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", paint)
```

All it does places a circle on the screen every time the `paint` function is invoked as long as the mouse has been clicked/held. However, the faster I move my mouse (I'm using Corona SDK) the more spaced out the circles become and it interrupts the flow of the line.

How could I change this so it draws a fluent line with no breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, what you're doing there is just putting a circle (hence the `display.newCircle`) whenever a touch event is triggered. The [touch event](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html) is triggered when you start touching the screen (click of mouse in simulator), when you move your finger on the screen, and when you unclick or take your finger off of the screen.

In your case, you are putting a circle 5 pixels in size where you first touch the screen, where ever the finger is moving, and where you lift your finger/mouse off of the screen. Your problem comes during the finger moving phase or when event.phase = "moved". This occurs because the number of touch events you get during the movement is limited depending on the hardware you use. Therefore, if the movement is large enough, you will have places in between your placed circles where your touch event, or the function `paint` in your case, was not called due to this limitation.

If you just want a line, one way you might do this is to use the [newLine](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newLine.html) method instead of the newCircle method. You would have to separate your touch inputs to their different phases, "began", "moved", "ended". During the "began" phase you would initiate your new line. During the "moved" or "ended" phase, you create (using newLine function) or add to your existing line with the [append](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/LineObject/append.html) function.

I have not tested this code, but it may look something like this:

```
local line                      --variable to hold the line object
local initX                     --initial X coordinate of touch
local initY                     --initial Y coordinate of touch
local lineCreated = false       --Flag to check if line is already created 

--Create the 'brush'
function paint(event)
    locationX = event.x
    locationY = event.y
    if event.phase == "began" then   --first touch
        --Delete previous line (in this case no multiple lines)
        if(line) then
            line:removeSelf()
            line = nil
        end

        --Set initX and initY with current touch location           
        initX = locationX       
        initY = locationY
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then   --during touch movement
        if lineCreated then
            --line has been created, just append to existing line
            line:append(locationX, locationY)
        else
            --Line has not been created
            --Make new line object, set color, and stroke width
            line = display.newLine(initX, initY, locationX, locationY)
            line:setStrokeColor( 0, 0, 1 )
            line.strokeWidth = 5

            --set line created flag to true
            lineCreated = true
        end     
    elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then --touch lifted
        --append last touch location to the line
        line:append(locationX, locationY)   
    end
    return true
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", paint)
```

This is a basic line so the corners may not be smooth. To make smooth lines you would need to apply algorithms that's a bit more complicated such as Bezier curve. There are many discussions on this for other programming languanges (the important thing is the algorithm, you can adopt it for Corona easily when you get more familiar with Lua, Lua is a relatively easy language to learn). You can get the math path [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31859/Draw-a-Smooth-Curve-through-a-Set-of-D-Points-wit), and one source for Corona can be found [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2010/12/12/bezier-curves-corona-source-code).